# E: Unable to locate package flannel

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management

I have searched the package `flannel` and I can see it on the [package manage website](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flannel/0.9.1~ds1-1), but when I tried the below instruction to install it…

```
root@iZhp3cq93udl83d2im5c82Z:~/flannel# apt-get install flannel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

I also have updated the package source by `apt update` and then tried the above instruction again. Sadly no success to install it again.

**Why can't install it? Is there any way to install `flannel`?**

My current Ubuntu version information show as following:

```
root@iZhp3cq93udl83d2im5c82Z:~/flannel# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? The [`flannel` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=flannel) first appeared in Ubuntu 17.10 (maybe also 17.04 which is no more supported but not 16.04 or older).

Comment: @Melebius I have already update my post, thank you for remind . How do i do if i don't want to update my OS?

Comment: Yep.  It's definitely not in [xenial](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&keywords=flannel) or [xenial-backports](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial-backports&keywords=flannel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [package information](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/flannel), flannel requires at least libc6 >= 2.17.

Judging by age, I'm guessing that libc6 2.17 wasn't yet released at the time xenial was originally released, so the package manager probably didn't want to guarantee it would work.

xenial is now at [libc6 2.23](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libc6), so if you download the .deb from artful [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/amd64/flannel/download) and then manually install it, it should run ok.

Comment: 16.04 development started with glibc 2.22, so I don't think that's the problem. It's far more likely that nobody bothered to package it until after. Glibc 2.17 is from 2012.